# Teradata Procedure throws Failed [5758 : HY000] MyProcedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, merge, teradata

I am facing an issue while executing a Terdata store-procedure that I am working on.

The purpose of this sproc is to move data from source table to a destination table (Staging to Actual) as part of a ETL Process

My source table look something like this:

> ACTUAL_ITEM_COMMENTS
>
> ITEM_NUM VARCHAR(18) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
>
> DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
>
> DESCRIPTION_SEQUENCE INTEGER,
>
> DESCRIPTION_TYPE VARCHAR(2) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC

and my destination table looks like this:
    **[UPDATED] Section**

> ITEM_COMMENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
>         (START WITH 1
>  
>          INCREMENT BY 1 
>          MINVALUE -2147483647
>  
>          MAXVALUE 2147483647
>  
>           NO CYCLE),
>
> STAGING_ITEM_COMMENTS
>
> ITEM_CD VARCHAR(18) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
>
> ITEM_COMMENT_TXT VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
>
> ITEM_COMMENT_TYPE_CD CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC

**[UPDATED] Section**

It seems that MERGE statement in Teradata do work fine when not mapping all fields while inserting (NOT MATCHING) data to the destination table

As I describe my destination table it includes an IDENTITY columns which I am not mapping in my **MERGE statement** which makes the procedure to throw an error like:

> **(Executed as Single statement.  Failed [5758 : HY000] MyProcedure:The search >condition must fully specify the Target table primary index and partition >column(s) and expression must match INSERT specification primary index and >partition column(s). 
>   Elapsed time = 00:01:33.616**

So I decided to try with a similar table as my destination by removing the IDENTITY column.

```
MERGE INTO "ODS_TABLES_TEST"."ITEM_COMMENT_TEST" ic   -- ITEM_COMMENT_TEST has no identity column defined on its DDL
USING 
(
    SELECT 
        "ITEM_NUM"
        ,"ITEM_COMMENT_TYPE_CD"
        ,"ITEM_COMMENT_TXT"
        ,'1048 ITEM COMMENT' AS "UPDATE_INTERFACE_NM"
        ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS "CREATE_DTTM"
        ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS "UPDATE_DTTM"
    FROM
        "ZZ_ITEM_COMMENT_FINAL"
) icb 
ON (icb."ITEM_NUM" = ic."ITEM_NUM" AND icb."ITEM_COMMENT_TYPE_CD" = ic."ITEM_COMMENT_TYPE_CD")
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET "ITEM_COMMENT_TXT" = icb."ITEM_COMMENT_TXT"
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ("ITEM_NUM", "ITEM_COMMENT_TYPE_CD", "ITEM_COMMENT_TXT", "UPDATE_INTERFACE_NM", "CREATE_DTTM", "UPDATE_DTTM" ) 
                       values(icb."ITEM_NUM", icb."ITEM_COMMENT_TYPE_CD", icb."ITEM_COMMENT_TXT", icb."UPDATE_INTERFACE_NM", icb."CREATE_DTTM", icb."UPDATE_DTTM") ;
```

Do I need always to map all columns while inserting?

Comment: You didn't tell if you actually created that error table before...

Comment: I found my issue and it was kind of I typo :(
I am updating this post to reflect the actual problem that I am facing.